# Remove object from a HashMap that use List as values

Tags: java

```
private static final Map<TeamType, List<Player>> LIST = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

How can i remove a Player object from the LIST? My code right now is:

```
for (List<Player> team : LIST.values())
{
    if (team.contains(ObjectIWantToRemove))
    {
        team.remove(ObjectIWantToRemove);
        return;
    }
}
```

But i want to improve using just a single line.

Comment: Did you try re-writing this code using java streams?

Comment: I would love to but i don't know how to do it. I try using removeIf but i won't work cause it will remove the entire entry.

Comment: Do you want to remove `ObjectIWantToRemove` from only the first element which contain `ObjectIWantToRemove` or from all elements?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to:

```
LIST.values().forEach(team -> team.remove(ObjectIWantToRemove));
```

---

**Edit**

The question is a little unclear, for that I will put this solution, so if you want to remove `ObjectIWantToRemove` from the first element which contain it, then you can use stream like this:

```
LIST.values().stream()
        .filter(team -> team.contains(ObjectIWantToRemove))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(team -> team.remove(ObjectIWantToRemove));
```

Comment: Not exactly the same as in the first post: If `ObjectIWantToRemove` is contained in multiple lists, all of them are removed, while the variant in the first post will only remove the first one that is found. Not sure if that is important.

Comment: @DorianGray agree, The question is a bit unclear, I will wait the OP confirmation, if it is the case I will edit my answer.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash can you show me how you test it please?

Comment: I doubt that an exception will be thrown, unless the Map itself contains immutable collections from the beginning. But then the task is impossible to solve.

Comment: @YCF_L If map value is immutable collection eg: `map.put(1, List.of(1,2))` then problem occours, otherwise it's fine

Comment: @Eklavya Then the task would be impossible to solve. Even the solution in the first post would fail.

Comment: @YCF_L - The second solution worked perfectly in my test.

Comment: @DorianGray  Not impossible. I just simplify the case and I believe OP don't use the immutable collection as map value

Comment: @Eklavya I think it is reasonable to assume that the start post contains a working solution.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I test it, check [my demo](https://ideone.com/ZhAmPQ)

Comment: @YCF_L - You missed my comment :) I confirmed 15 minutes ago that your solution worked perfectly. My doubt was because I had immutable lists inside the map in my mind.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash oops, Sorry I don't see it :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is this:

```
for (List<Player> team : LIST.values()) {
     if (team.remove(ObjectIWantToRemove))
     {
         return;
     }
}
```

This will  avoid the call to `contains` before removing the element.

If you want to do it in one line, you can do it like  that:

```
LIST.values().forEach(team -> team.remove(ObjectIWantToRemove));
```

That will remove the player from all teams it belongs to, whereas the solution above only remove it from the first one.

If you are looking for a solution that removes it only from the first, there already is an answer.

Comment: Still the idea is to do it using J8 stream in 1 line.

Comment: I added Stream variant to my post

Comment: filter as a terminal operation, do you find it better than forEach? as well +1 to the 1st solution

Comment: Doesn't matter, I changed it.

Comment: no need to `.stream()` if you want to use forEach as :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
LIST.values().stream().filter(team -> team.remove(ObjectIWantToRemove)).findFirst();
```

`List.remove(Object)` returns true if the team contained the `ObjectIWantToRemove`.
This expression selects only the first team that contain `ObjectIWantToRemove`.

Answer (score 0):

This uses Integers and Strings to demonstrate but could also be applied to your classes.

```
LIST.put("A", new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,4,2,3,1)));
LIST.put("B", new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2, 9, 10,2)));
LIST.put("C", new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,5,2, 9, 1)));
LIST.put("D", new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,3,2,4,2)));


Integer ObjectToRemove = 2;

System.out.println("Before remove");
LIST.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);


LIST.forEach((k,v)->v.removeIf(r->r.equals(ObjectToRemove)));

System.out.println("After remove");
LIST.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Before remove
A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1]
B=[1, 2, 9, 10, 2]
C=[1, 2, 5, 2, 9, 1]
D=[1, 3, 2, 4, 2]
After remove
A=[1, 3, 4, 3, 1]
B=[1, 9, 10]
C=[1, 5, 9, 1]
D=[1, 3, 4]
```

Even though this removes all Objects, I would assume (perhaps wrongly) that a player would not be listed twice for the same team.  If you just want to remove the first one encountered, then use this construct.

```
LIST.forEach((k,v)->v.remove(ObjectToRemove));
```